# Configuring spring.http.multipart.max-file-size ignores size or returns stream closed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, file-upload

I have a spring-boot application version 1.3.3.RELEASE running Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE

Below I have some of the items I have tried to resolve this. My questions:

- Do I need to define my own multipart resolver?
- Why is Spring/Tomcat not picking up my multipart settings?

I am trying to accept Multipart files over 1MB. I have configured what appears to be the appropriate config

```
# Spring http settings
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=11MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=11MB
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to have any affect:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException:
>   The field files exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

It doesn't seem to be making it past Tomcat at this point. After a little research I tried to add my own multipart resolver.

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

This returns a new error of which has me stumped:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream closed

My request looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  /application/75dc9981-61ac-4fa0-b316-790b764230a3/pending \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F files=@/Users/paulscoder/Documents/sticky_phalcon_header.gif
```

And my Request mapping looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/application/{applicationId}/pending",
            method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFiles(
            @PathVariable("applicationId") UUID applicationId,
            @RequestParam(value = "docId", required = false) String docId,
            @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type,
            @RequestParam(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files) throws Exception {...
```

Comment: You are using Spring boot 1.3 but are using the properties for Spring boot 1.5 and up that will obviously not work. Either upgrade or remove the `spring.http` prefix. For future reference see [the correct guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: is there any gateway or any other service forward your request to this actually service? If yes, all the way which the request pass through need to have these kind of configuration.